# Updated AMA.bst file?

Tags: bibtex

Dear LaTeX/BibTeX gurus,

I have one final hurdle to overcome to satisfy my university's thesis editors: proper bibliography formatting. Throughout the entire process I simply declared `\bibliographystyle{ama}` and of course included the most updated ama.bst file I can find (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/ama.bst) in the working directory. I hadn't really scrutinized the bibliography, but the thesis editor pointed out that author names are not being abbreviated and article titles are not using proper capitalization (i.e., capitalizing only the first letter of the title, in general). Instructions at the top of the `ama.bst` file provide an example that suggests the file should handle those requirements, but there is also a note that the present version does not work in BibTeX 0.98i. My current version is 0.99d, so I assume `ama.bst` "simply" needs updated. :)

Has anyone else come across an updated `ama.bst` file or know how to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make a copy of the file `ama.bst` and call it, say, `myama.bst`. To force BibTeX to abbreviate all first (and middle) names, perform the following edit in the new file: You need to find and replace the two instances of `{ff }` with `{f. }`; these should be located on lines 241 and 533 if you use the version for which

Second, to use "sentence style" capitalization (instead of "book title style capitalization) of titles, locate the function `format.title` (on l. 278, most likely) and replace the line

```
{ title " " *}
```

with

```
{ title "t" change.case$ add.period$}
```

There's a second, similar-named function, `format.title.p`, a few lines further down in the .bst file. You may have to change the line `{ title " " *}` in that function to `{ title "t" change.case$ add.period$}` as well.

Save the file and start using it with the directive `\bibliographystyle{myama}`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I also found from another .bst that if I use `{f{}}` then it will not use periods in author initials, as is required by ama. So do you have any idea why nobody has ever corrected these issues since '02? More importantly, is there somewhere I can submit these updates?

Comment: Sorry, one more question: I noticed the article title doesn't have a period at the end. Do you know how to correct that?

Comment: @zugzug: Regarding your first comment -- I have no idea why the `ama.bst` style file has apparently been languishing without further updates for ten years. The header information states that it was last changed by Eric Kort, email eric.kort@vai.org. You could try emailing him and see if he either still maintains the file or knows somebody who does.

Comment: @zugzug: On your second comment -- I've augmented the instructions to add the string `add.period$`. Hope you're in business now.

Comment: I just tried emailing Eric but it was returned as undeliverable. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: revisiting an old question here, but how can be adjust `myama` so references are listed in alphabetical order and not the order they are used?

Comment: @lukeg - Adding alphabetical sorting would be a non-trivial task. :-) May I ask you create a new query to raise this question? That way, it'll also be seen by lots more people.